# admin menu is not showing in Magento custom module

Tags: magento

I have created custom module everything is fine but its not showing admin menu.As I can see in configuration->advanced,the module is showing there and enabled.I also created a fresh module from http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator and installed to same site but its behaving same as above explained.I have installed same module at another magento installation on another server,its working fine.please help .Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Irphan

Comment: Clear the cache and disable compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to clear the cache ? I've done one litle project in magento for school and clear cache solve all kind of problems.

Comment: yes I have cleared cache.I have tried everything that I could do.I have checked disabling the cache but no success.

Answer (score 0):

The Best way I prefer to create a Module in Magento is Using the Module Creator

https://github.com/shell/Magento-Module-Creator

There could me many reasons Why your module dosent appear in the adminhtml.you might be missin some line in the xml file, or some functions model.